# Converting false to pointer type void*?

Tags: c++, stream, boolean, type-conversion

Can someone explain me what is going on here...?

I had this code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
int main(){   
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");    
    std::string x;
    while (true) { 
        if (!(file >> x)) return 0;
        std::cout << x << "\n";   
    }
}
```

...compiles fine, does what it is supposed to do, no problem so far. Sometimes I dont like the `!` so much, because it can be overlooked easily, so I replaced the `if` with

```
if ((file >> x)==false) return 0;
```

..and suddenly my compiler (gcc 4.8.5) complains with a warning:

```
 warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘void*’ [-Wconversion-null]
     if ((file >> x)==false) return 0;
```

and this is where I am starting to be puzzled. Where is the `void*` coming from? Doesnt `>>` return a reference that should be casted to a `bool`? Why is `false` converted to `void*`? Why isnt the same warning triggered when I dont explicitly write `false`?

Out of curiosity I also tried this:

```
if ((file>>x)==true) return 0;
```

which causes a storm of errors starting with

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ and ‘bool’)
 if ((file>>x)==true) return 0;
              ^
```

and now I am completely lost. How is `false` a differnt `bool` than `true`? Different values of course, but I always thought `true` and `false` are of same type.

Comment: The `void *` overload was removed in C++11 , I'd suggest using modern C++

Comment: @M.M are you sure? I get exactly same warning when compiling with `-std=c++11`. Maybe gcc forgot to remove it

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that C++ has operator overloads.  In particular, `std::basic_istream` [overloads `operator!`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!).

Alas, there is no enforcement that operator overloads are semantically consistent, so there is no overload for `==` between an `istream` and a `bool`.  Thus the comparison with `true` fails.  However, the compiler is also allowed to apply implicit conversions in order to make an expression compile - in this case `false` may be implicitly converted to a null pointer, and `basic_istream` has an [overload of `operator void*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) (though apparently that was replaced with `operator bool` in C++11 - presuambly to fix the inconsistency).

Comment: ok first mystery resolved. What about `==` working with `false` but not with `true`? Afaik overloads are about types not values

Comment: @tobi303 - Ah, I didn't see that second part of the question.  Will add an update.

Comment: ..... `false` can be converted to `nullptr` but there exists no such conversion for `true`, is it that?

Comment: @tobi303 - Yup, exactly that.

Comment: somehow I knew all the pieces, but without help I wasnt able to put them together to solve the knot in my brain caused by the usually weird error messages. Thanks for the help

Comment: well, not really "usually weird". I would say that this is a unusually weird case even for c++

Comment: would you mind adding to your answer, that the problem can be completely avoided by a `static_cast<bool>` (no warning for `false` and even ok with the `true` case)?